# Finding the last elements of the pandas dataframe that are a certain time apart

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas dataframe with two columns **time** and **value**. For simplicity, **time** and **value** are integers. I specify the number \delta t. I need to create a new column **latest_value** which will contain the element from the **value** column such that its **time** is the maximal time that is less than or equal to **time - \delta t**.

For example, if **\delta t=10** and the dataframe is given by

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 25 | 4 |
| 36 | 5 |
| 41 | 6 |

Should output

| time | value | latest_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 | nan |
| 15 | 1 | nan |
| 16 | 2 | nan |
| 20 | 3 | 0 |
| 25 | 4 | 1 |
| 36 | 5 | 4 |
| 41 | 6 | 4 |

The **time** column is sorted.

I know the solution with the rolling window but it takes too much time.

```
def latest_value_Xms_apart(timestamps, values, lag=0.05):
    current_timestamp = timestamps.iloc[-1]
    mask = (current_timestamp - timestamps) >= lag
    
    if mask.any():
        latest_value = values[mask].iloc[-1]
        return latest_value
    else:
        return np.nan


df['latest_value'] = df['timestamp'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=1).apply(
    lambda x: latest_value_Xms_apart(x, df.loc[x.index, 'value']), raw=False
)
```

here I assume that we can always find the required element in the last 100 observations prior to the element of interest as otherwise my code simply takes too much time.

Comment: `Series` method `searchsorted` may help.

Comment: Yes, this might work if the time complexity is sub-quadratic. Thanks, let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in comments Series.searchsorted solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df['latest_value'] = pd.merge_asof(df, df.eval('time=time+10'), on='time')['value_y']
```

Output:

```
   time  value  latest_value
0    10      0           NaN
1    15      1           NaN
2    16      2           NaN
3    20      3           0.0
4    25      4           1.0
5    36      5           4.0
6    41      6           4.0
```